# How to transpose a ragged tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow

Everything is in the title.

I have a RaggedTensor of shape `(nsamples, None, M1)`, and I would like to transpose the last two axes to get a RaggedTensor of shape `(nsamples, M1, None)`.

`tf.transpose` does not work on ragged tensors, nor `tf.linalg.matrix_transpose` (as they are the same function).

Is there a way to do it purely in Tensorflow or do I have to do a (slow) `for` loop manually ?

Answer (score 0):

First, I hope this answer can help some people (including myself) in the future despite being years late to the original question.

### Swapping axes 1 and 2 for ragged tensor with `ragged_rank=1`

For the question at hand, it is possible to achieve the desired transpose with [`tf.map_fn()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/map_fn#:%7E:text=the%20above%20types.-,RaggedTensors,-map_fn%20supports%20tf).

```py
def swap_dims_1_2(rt: tf.RaggedTensor):
    dtype = rt.flat_values.dtype
    
    def _fn(_t):
        return tf.RaggedTensor.from_tensor(tf.transpose(_t, [1, 0]))
    
    output_shape = (rt.flat_values.shape[1], None)
    return tf.map_fn(_fn, rt, fn_output_signature=tf.RaggedTensorSpec(shape=output_shape, dtype=dtype))
```

Here's a small test:

```py
data = [
    [[1, 2]], 
    [[3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8], [9, 10]], 
    [[11, 12], [13, 14]],
]

rt: tf.RaggedTensor = tf.ragged.constant(data, ragged_rank=1)
print(rt.shape)  # (3, None, 2)
print(rt.nested_row_lengths())

r2 = swap_dims_1_2(rt)
print(r2)
print(r2.shape)  # (3, 2, None)
print(r2.nested_row_lengths())
```

We can also pad the ragged tensor to regular tensor and then transpose, which is likely not desirable, but can be used as a check for the correctness of the function above:

```py
# ... 
# `rt` was created same as above 

t = rt.to_tensor(default_value=0)  # shape (3, 4, 2)
t_transpose = tf.transpose(t, perm=[0, 2, 1])  # shape (3, 2, 4)

rt_transpose = tf.ragged.boolean_mask(t_transpose, mask=t_transpose>0)
rt_transpose._set_shape([None, 2, None])
print(rt_transpose)
print(rt_transpose.shape)  # (3, 2, None)
print(rt_transpose.nested_row_lengths())
```

### Note on transposing ragged tensors

In general, transposing dimensions in ragged tensors is not possible without filling some padding values, particularly when multiple ragged dimensions are involved. We can think of it this way: a tensor, ragged or not, is a nested list of lists. Transposing a tensor means reordering the level of nesting, and the resulting tensor's inner lists can contain elements of original tensor at a uniform stride. This becomes problematic for ragged tensors because "elements at a uniform stride" is not well-defined for certain dimensions.

Therefore, when thinking about "transposing ragged tensor" or "swapping axes in ragged tensor", it's better to write down an example and see if the desired effect really is achieved by the supposed transpose op.